# How to clean style sheets mess?

Tags: css, asp.net-mvc, browser, stylesheet

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [How to clean up styles in a large web site?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8120048/how-to-clean-up-styles-in-a-large-web-site)

Is there any kind of parsing tool, which can scan my *.css file across all pages of my web application and organize its content ? By organizing I mean throw out redundant inputs, unify selectors which duplicate each other's behavior, and so on.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Im not sure of a program that will go through all your files. but this one will do it one at a time

http://www.cleancss.com/ and http://www.lonniebest.com/FormatCSS/

Answer (score 0):

I've used [CleanCSS](http://www.cleancss.com/) to great extent.

It's not your ideal solution- It can't scan a directory, but you can copy/paste the contents of your css files and it will condense all of the duplicate selectors and properties.