# Remove unused css code

Tags: html, css, coding-style

A Website im working on for several years now gets bigger and bigger.. CSS-Files are not very clear right now..

How am i able to find out which code of my huge css-file is not used on my homepage? So that im able to delete this?

I recently found this:
[Removing unused CSS from website code](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12091356/removing-unused-css-from-website-code)

The Problem is, my page got of course multiple pages. I should know which css code is not used in all of the pages.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Can you check the method given here on using [uncss](http://davidwalsh.name/uncss). This parses your site and produces a css with only the used styles.

Answer (score 0):

If you are familiar with node js you can also use "find unused css": https://www.npmjs.com/package/find-unused-css

This scans your html files and find out the unused css selectors. Currently it only supports class and id selectors.