# How to find css artifacts?

Tags: css

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [How to clean up styles in a large web site?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8120048/how-to-clean-up-styles-in-a-large-web-site)

I usually mockup directly with html/css, and over time get some hard-to-find css artifacts. Not generating errors, but simply waste of space.

Is there any tool/browser-plugin to find css-artifacts, (rules that's never get applied on the page).

//EDIT//

*I guess "rules" is somewhat vague, I'm talking about non-existant id's and classes, not single css-attributes*.

regards,

Comment: i don't think so, i also never run in to this situation. Maybe your way of doing CSS is wrong? Maybe.

Comment: [deadweight](https://github.com/aanand/deadweight) is a great tool.

Answer (score 1):

you can use

> Dust-Me Selectors

[Find unused CSS](https://addons.mozilla.org/en-US/firefox/addon/dust-me-selectors/) 
An Add-on for FireFox

also online tool on

> http://unused-css.com/

Comment: will evaluate this as well as https://addons.mozilla.org/en-US/firefox/addon/css-usage/, thanks.